# innerHtml and innerText destroys tabs in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, innerhtml

I want to take the content of a textarea and put it in a `<pre>`. Problem is that if i set the innerHTML-property of the pre to the value of the textarea all tabs and linebreaks will be removed in Internet Explorer. If i use innerText instead of innerHtml i will get the line-breaks but tabs still disappear. Works fine in other browsers.

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a DOM Text node:

```
pre.innerHTML= '';
pre.appendChild(document.createTextNode('A\tB\r\nC'));
```

The Windows-style newline (`\r\n`) is bogus (DOM content should always have newlines normalised to `\n`), but seems to be necessary in IE for some reason.